# Efficiently generating the cartesian product of lists with > 50 elements

Tags: ocaml, combinations, cartesian-product

I am trying to generate all possible combinations from a list over 50 elements, I was working in a previous implementation with this function:

```
let rec extract k list =
  if k <= 0 then [ [] ]
  else 
    match list with
    | [] -> []
    | h :: tl ->
        let with_h = List.map (fun l -> h :: l) (extract (k-1) tl) in
        let without_h = extract k tl in
        with_h @ without_h
```

And everything was OK, the point is that in my previous application the size of the list was small, between 5 and 10 items. However now my list will in some cases have more than 50 items, and this and other functions for generating combinations crash (with overflow memory messages in some cases). Is there a way to generate a function that can manage to generate combinations with very big lists?

Comment: There's a few different implementations on Rosetta Code, including a tail recursive one that should perform better: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_two_or_more_lists#OCaml

Comment: I have to admit I am a bit perplex: are you asking for all possible sublists of `k` elements, or for the cartisian product? Your question asks for the latter, but your code indicates the former.

Comment: In fact, my question is related to generating all possible sublists of k elements. My original title of the question was edited, and change for asking about the cartesian product, but my first title was:  How to generate combinations of k elements from a list over 50 items. All the solucitions I tried works fine for item approx 30 items but for 50 items the function crash.

Answer (score 3):

A generic solution is to switch to sequences in order to lazily compute elements of the combination:

```
let rec extract k list () =
  if k <= 0 then Seq.return [] ()
  else match list with
  | [] -> Seq.Nil
  | h :: tl ->
     let with_h = Seq.map (fun l -> h :: l) (extract (k-1) tl) in
     let without_h = extract k tl in
     Seq.append with_h without_h ()


let test = extract 20 (List.init 1_000_000 Fun.id)
let view = List.of_seq (Seq.take 20 l)
```

This solution avoids both the issue of stack overflows due to non-tailrecursive functions and the issue of eagerly generating a list of size `n^k` which would not fit in memory for large `n`.